# The next background image is not updated when I press on the button to go to the next frame

Tags: grease-pencil

I'm trying to make this tutorial :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zmZ0gVLTTB4&t=180s

Go to minute 3:00,please. He loaded a list of png files and he gone until the last one. When he pressed the button to go on the latest frame,the background image on the 3D window of blender has been changed with the latest image on the list. I did the same,but in my case if I press the button to go on the next frame,I see always the first image of the list. Do you know why ? thanks.

PS : I added my blender file.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how many images are in your folder but you selected to just show 2 of them. Try bump up the number and see if it works. Your file did not have any images so could only test with my own samples but it works as advertised...

[image]

Comment: ok. check here my pictures : https://postimg.org/image/wqi569bbn/ and here what I did : https://sendvid.com/xc3czyuu

Comment: You are making it more complicated than it is. You load the images. Then you increase the frame count that I boxed in the image above. Return to the time line and play. In your video you play with the Timeline, the return it to frame one, then play with the Frame count, but don't return to check it in the Timeline.

Comment: When I reach the frame 23,the image should change,because the woman moves her glasses over her eyes,but this does not happen in my case. Check here,the picture number 23 :

https://postimg.org/image/wqi569bbn/

and check here,that when I increase the frame number,the image is still the same,it does not reflect the images located inside the folder where they  are :

https://sendvid.com/1un9g3m4

Comment: You loaded from Image 00001 which would correspond to Frame 1. If you want to see Image 23, then you need to be on Frame 23 in the Timeline too.They work together...